# How to effectively pause a game in spritekit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

This seems like such a basic concept but there is really no good answer.

I currently have a pretty basic setup, in my game's scene, I have an `enum gameState` which is currently either `inGame` or `gamePaused`.

I have my button set up, and I have it so pressing simply toggles `gameState`.

Then, to make it work, I have two separate update methods: One for when `gamePaused`, one for when `inGame`.

This works for 95% of my game, as the updates in my game can be pretty readily started and stopped without any issues. There are some issues I cannot tackle though.

First and foremost are actions. I use `SKActions` for a bit of my project (some movement, scaling, fading...) and this method does NOT pause them. This can be catastrophic in certain points. Secondly, this doesn't handle particles, physics, and a few other things that are not directly associated to my update methods.

The only clue I have is `self.view.paused = YES`, but that isn't going to work either.

First off, this DOES fix my actions, particles, and physics problem... kinda. But [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383507/pause-skaction-after-clicking-the-pause-button-spritekit?lq=1) suggests that `SKActions` aren't actually PAUSED by this, but actually STOPPED completely. Is this true? If it is, then it won't work smoothly either because my actions are thrown out of whack.

Also, pausing the view seems to do what it says: stop everything. EVERYTHING. Newbie question here, but how am I supposed to get any code to run at that point? It's all cut off. Is this where I need `subViews`? I have never used a `subView` yet, but it sounds like its what I want in this case.

Simply put, there are a lot of unanswered questions for me, and I don't know how to proceed. I'm hoping there's some 'standard procedure' for pausing in `Sprite Kit`, but with pausing the view halting actions I truly have no idea where to proceed.

Should I move away from using actions? Is my idea of a pause `subView` sound?

I don't want to babble, all I want to know is how you go about pausing in your average `Sprite Kit` project. Additional info provided upon request.

Comment: 1. Try setting actions speed to 0.0. 2. Try setting scene's paused to YES. 3. Try setting self.view.paused to YES 4. Try combinations of these three.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pausing a node will pause (not stop) the node's actions, and i suppose pause will also be applied to all children of the paused node in the same way. All other unpaused nodes will continue to run their actions to completion.

You should have a "game layer" node with all game nodes in them that you want to pause, and then just pause that "game layer" node. Then have a "pause game menu" node where you add all the pause menu stuff you need which will continue to function normally even if the game layer is paused.

Be very sure you do not use `performSelector` or `NSTimer` or GCD or any other scheduling methods besides actions or the scene's update: method because those will not adhere to a node's paused state.

Pausing the view effectively freezes everything in it, pausing the scene according to some will not pause the update: calls - but I have not verified this myself. If this were the case you can always check inside the update method whether a given node that you send a message to is paused and if so, decide not to send certain messages to that node.

Comment: This seems to work best, can't believe I missed it though... Pausing nodes does not stop actions, and by pausing my game layer the foundation of my pause button is completed. I didn't realize individual nodes could be paused, and doing so affects the children as well... thanks. By the way, all other advice in this thread was useful as well :)

Comment: This was the best! My head hurts a bit due to it constantly being banged on the wall before reading your answer :) Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

I just called a map function on all children of the scene and set the paused property to true

```
self.children.map{($0 as SKNode).paused = false}
```

By setting it to true you can easily undo the freeze.

**EDIT:**
Better use a for-loop to iterate over the children.

```
for node in self.children as [SKNode] {
    node.paused = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you what I did in ***my*** game:

1. Pause the `SKView` on `-applicationWillResignActive:` (or equivalent, using `NSNotification`s),
2. Un-pause the `SKView` on `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` (or equivalent, using `NSNotification`s),

For the actual game scene only, I set a boolean flag `_isPaused` when resigning active, and if it is true I just skip the `-update:` method (frame updates). (I also show the "paused" menu when the user resumes the app).

...But my game is a simple puzzle game, and there's no long actions that should continue past the pause/resume. I can not confirm right now that all actions are aborted, but I think it's **not** the case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I need to sleep now but I will definitely look into this. I will also test the action aborting question, which I couldn't find out how to do because my code went dead on the view pausing. Your method almost seems to simple to work as-is, but it will certainly give me a foundation. In the meantime I welcome new info from others :) cheers

Comment: Great, let me know if you fix it, and how. The more ideas, the merrier.

Answer (score 0):

I also used `self.children.map{($0 as SKNode).paused = false}` and it does work if you create a var layer of type SKSpriteNode and add it on top of the scene. But I also have an NSTimer I'm using to spawn sprites on the scene. Everything currently on the scene is paused, but sprites keep appearing and moving across the screen. It is not pausing the spawning.

I tried pausing the NSTimer when I call the above code by setting repeats to false, then setting it to true when I remove the layer but it doesn't work. I also tried `self.scene?.view?.paused = true` but that freezes everything and the layer I create does not even appear onscreen.

Answer (score 0):

This function is work perfectly if you are not using the `NSTimer` to call a function. If you use NSTimer your view will pause perfectly but when you play the game again by play game functionality you see that all the functions that use the NSTimer function that runs in the back end and your screen full with your `sprite-kits`. So when you use `NSTimer` in the function you have to first pause the NSTimer functions also after that this function work perfectly.

```
//For Pause
func pauseGame() {
    scene?.view?.paused = true
}

//For play.
func playGame() { 
  scene?.view?.paused = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate for the View!

```
func PauseGame(){
   self.scene.view.paused = true
}

fun playGame(){
   self.scene.pause = false
}
```